# how would one get methods exposed in a webAPI project?

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

How can I programatically get a list of public methods w/parameters that are exposed in my webAPI project?  I need to provide this list to our QA dept.  I dont want to compile and maintain the list myself. I want to provide a link for QA to find the methods on their own.  I need something like what you get when you browse to an .asmx file.

Comment: Web API provides HelpPage...for more you can look at this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/08/15/introducing-the-asp-net-web-api-help-page-preview.aspx

Comment: Note that the above video is more than year old, but it could still give you some useful info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASP.NET Web API lets you create a help page automatically. That help pages documents all endpoints provided by your API. Please refer to this blog post: [Creating Help Pages for ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages).

You can, of course, create an entirely custom documentation by leveraging the `IApiExplorer` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
public static void Main() 
    {
        Type myType =(typeof(MyTypeClass));
        // Get the public methods.
        MethodInfo[] myArrayMethodInfo = myType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe number of public methods is {0}.", myArrayMethodInfo.Length);
        // Display all the methods.
        DisplayMethodInfo(myArrayMethodInfo);
        // Get the nonpublic methods.
        MethodInfo[] myArrayMethodInfo1 = myType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe number of protected methods is {0}.", myArrayMethodInfo1.Length);
        // Display information for all methods.
        DisplayMethodInfo(myArrayMethodInfo1);      
    }
    public static void DisplayMethodInfo(MethodInfo[] myArrayMethodInfo)
    {
        // Display information for all methods. 
        for(int i=0;i<myArrayMethodInfo.Length;i++)
        {
            MethodInfo myMethodInfo = (MethodInfo)myArrayMethodInfo[i];
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe name of the method is {0}.", myMethodInfo.Name);
        }
    }
```

I got it from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quote from Scott Gu that answers your question:

> > Web API doesn't directly support WSDL or SOAP.  You can use the WCF REST support if you want to use a WCF/WSDL based model to support both SOAP and REST though.

Your question was asked and answered here as well:
[ASP.NET Web API interface (WSDL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500037/asp-mvc-4-web-api-interface-wsdl)

Hope that helps.