# Asp.NET Web API Displaying all controller's routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Is there a way to display all the available services that the application exposes via Web Api actions? For example when a user goes to http://someurl/api/ he will get a list of all the available services, their descriptions and the required parameters? I remember that I've seen this once but I cannot find any documentation for it/

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500037/asp-net-web-api-interface-wsdl

Comment: didn't find there any reference for what I'm looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer following URL

> http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages

you can also customize the help page as per your requirement.

Comment: Can you please add enough detail to your answer so that it answers the question and uses the link as a reference?

Answer (score 9):

Found the answer! ASP.NET Web API has a feature called "[Help Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages)" it allows to display all the allowed actions and a description. It is generated automatically. 
[image]